# find eigenvalue and eigenvector of given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The matrix:

\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 & 2 \\ 5 & -3 & 3  \\ -1 & 0 & -2 \end{pmatrix}

so as per workflow I got:

$$\mathrm{det}(A-\lambda{E}) = \begin{pmatrix} 2-\lambda & -1 & -2 \\ 5 & -3-\lambda & 3 \\ -1 & 0 & -2-\lambda \end{pmatrix}$$

After all calculus I got some cubic equation:

$$\lambda^3 -7\lambda^2 +23\lambda -31 =0$$

which has really strange roots (as far as I remember they are $\lt 1)$

Is it normal, or have I done mistake in the proccess?

Comment: What roots did you get?

Comment: for checking the eigenvalues; you may try wolfram alpha

Comment: @AlgorithmsX, as real only $x = -1$, and some complex ones, but complex ones are not possible here as per task level and answers, so it seems I am doing something wrong

Comment: The top right entry of your matrix $A-\lambda E$ magically became $-2$.

Comment: Your characteristic polynomial should be $-(\lambda+1)^3$

Comment: Actually it should be $(\lambda + 1)^3$.

Comment: @Ken Duna Yes. Corrected. Besided what do you mean by "magically became..." ?

Comment: Can someone explain me a bit how to choose it properly then? :] I am a bit confused about the right way

Comment: @JeanMarie It was a $2$ in the original matrix. There was a clerical error in which it became a $-2$. I just like using colorful language when talking about math.

Comment: Cf. http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordandecomposition+%7B%7B2%2C-1%2C2%7D%2C%7B5%2C-3%2C3%7D%2C%7B-1%2C0%2C-2%7D%7D&x=0&y=0

Comment: The eigenvectorspace is one dimensional spaned by the vector $(-1,-1,1)$. This shows that the matrix is not diagonalizable.

Comment: The trace is -3 which is a giveaway that you do not have the correct characteristic equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have:
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 & 2 \\ 5 & -3 & 3  \\ -1 & 0 & -2 \end{bmatrix} $$
then we find the eigenvalues by solving the characteristic equation:
$$ p(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda I) = 0  $$
We see that
\begin{align*}
p(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda I) 
&= \begin{vmatrix} 2-\lambda & -1 & 2 \\ 5 & -3-\lambda & 3  \\ -1 & 0 & -2-\lambda \end{vmatrix} \\
&= -1 \cdot \begin{vmatrix} -1 & 2 \\ -3-\lambda & 3  \end{vmatrix} + (-2-\lambda) \begin{vmatrix} 2-\lambda & -1 \\ 5 & -3-\lambda \end{vmatrix} \\
&= (-3-2\lambda)+(-2-\lambda)\left[(2-\lambda)(-3-\lambda)+5 \right] \\
&= -3-2\lambda - \left[(4-\lambda^2)(-3-\lambda)+5(2+\lambda) \right] \\
&= -3-2\lambda - \left[(\lambda^3-4\lambda + 3\lambda^2-12)+(10+5\lambda) \right] \\
&= -3-2\lambda - \left(\lambda^3+\lambda + 3\lambda^2-2 \right) \\
&= -\left(\lambda^3+3\lambda + 3\lambda^2+1 \right) \\
&= -(\lambda+1)^3
\end{align*}
Therefore, $A$ has only one eigenvalue, $\lambda = -1$.

The set of eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $-1$ is the nullspace of $A+I$, which we row reduce as follows:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix} 3 & -1 & 2 \\ 5 & -2 & 3  \\ -1 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \implies
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & -2 & -2  \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \implies
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1  \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
So we see that the nullspace of $A+I$, the set of eigenvectors of $A$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda = -1$, is spanned by the following vector:
$$ \mathbf{v}_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} $$